# Зашифровать перезаписываемый файл в С#

Tags: c#

есть бот помощник для биржи, помогите с защитой.Он создаёт текстовый файл с апи и секретом в каталоге, но как его не засовывай все равно легко найти, как можно его зашифровать или вообще что бы не писал ,мне достаточно если я в коде где то его пропишу и все раз и навсегда.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// загрузить настройки сервера из файла
    /// </summary>
    public void Load()
    {
        if (!File.Exists(@"socket\" + @"api.txt"))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"socket\" + @"api.txt"))
            {
                UserId = reader.ReadLine();
                UserKey = reader.ReadLine();
                _countDaysTickNeadToSave = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
                _neadToSaveTicks = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.ReadLine());
                IsDemo = Convert.ToBoolean(reader.ReadLine());

                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// сохранить настройки сервера в файл
    /// </summary>
    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"socket\" + @"api.txt", false))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(UserId);
                writer.WriteLine(UserKey);
                writer.WriteLine(CountDaysTickNeadToSave);
                writer.WriteLine(NeadToSaveTicks);
                writer.WriteLine(IsDemo);

                writer.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }
    }
```

Помощник в открытом доступе нашел, вот и хочу переделать под себя, а страшно оставлять на сервере например.
Я просто только не давно изучаю , помогите, пожалуйста.
Нашел пример но не могу сообразить как хотя бы параметр UserKey шифровать и расшифровывать.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ushort secretKey = 0x0088; // Секретный ключ (длина - 16 bit).


        string str = "Hello World"; //это строка которую мы зашифруем

        str = EncodeDecrypt(str, secretKey); //производим шифрование
        Console.WriteLine(str);  //выводим в консоль зашифрованную строку

        str = EncodeDecrypt(str, secretKey); //производим рассшифровку 
        Console.WriteLine(str);             //выводим в консоль расшифрованную строку
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

    public static string EncodeDecrypt(string str, ushort secretKey)
    {
        var ch = str.ToArray(); //преобразуем строку в символы
        string newStr = "";      //переменная которая будет содержать зашифрованную строку
        foreach (var c in ch)  //выбираем каждый элемент из массива символов нашей строки
            newStr += TopSecret(c, secretKey);  //производим шифрование каждого отдельного элемента и сохраняем его в строку
        return newStr;
    }

    public static char TopSecret(char character, ushort secretKey)
    {
        character = (char)(character ^ secretKey); //Производим XOR операцию
        return character;
    }
```

Или вот тоже пример но как его применить не пойму:

```
// Шифруем текст, и записываем его в файл

FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\mytext.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);

DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
   cryptic.CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Write);


byte[] data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World!");

crStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);

crStream.Close();
stream.Close();   
//Дешифруем текст и выводим результат дешифрации в консоль

FileStream stream = new FileStream("C:\\mytext.txt", 
                              FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);

DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptic = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

cryptic.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");
cryptic.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ABCDEFGH");

CryptoStream crStream = new CryptoStream(stream,
    cryptic.CreateDecryptor(),CryptoStreamMode.Read);

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(crStream);

string data = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(data);
Console.ReadKey();

reader.Close();
stream.Close();
```

Comment: Крайне нежелательно хранить любые конфиденциальные данные в коде - они легко читаются открытием .exe/.dll через любой хекс-редактор.

Comment: да уже знаю спасибо, но это делали программисты и выложили в открытый доступ ,вот и хотелось бы как то зашифровать. идеально вообще что бы это оставалось внутри кода я и  сам могу туда нужные вписать .

Comment: Чем не устраивает вариант с фалом config.txt на сервере, в котором хранились бы все настройки? Разумеется, что нужно запретить доступ к этому файлу извне, а в остальном безопасный способ.

Comment: ерунда это всё, ну зашифруете, далее нужно дешифрировать здесь и начнутся основные проблемы: Юзер запускает дебагер и видит всё.

Comment: А воспользоваться [ProtectedData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) можете? Если вам нужно, чтобы посторонний пользователь не мог прочесть, то можете этим классом воспользоваться, если хотите вообще ото всех спрятать, то тут локально никак.

Comment: А можно как то вписать вместо UserId и UserKey сразу значения которые биржа даёт? что бы вообще обойтись без этих данных в файле. А как указать путь для хранения на сервере правильно, идея неплоха,спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае надо использовать ХЭШ-коды (одностороннее шифрование). Пример можете посмотреть, например здесь: "Класс для работы с паролями в среде .NET" на сайте http://rsdn.org/